# MongoDB Java Driver version 3.x.x error on Android

Tags: java, android, mongodb, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem with **compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.x.x'** on Android Studion. I am getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

**The error do not appear with 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.x.x'** So i suppose that it is rather a jdk problem or a problem from mongo driver version 3.x.x.

Here is my gradle file too.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.irakl_000.maps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.13'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.9.2' //.....//
}
```

**EDIT:**
On a new project the version 3.x.x has no errors on gradle. So jdk should not be a problem. So could it be some kind of limit on size of compile file error like the 65K Limit error?

Comment: Why go from Android to mongodb? Make a Backend server with a webservice. Then other devices could share it etc...

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean and rebuild? Usually that solves errors like this.

Comment: Hello kevin thanks for the interest. I managed to solve the problem. The problem had to do with the limit of 65k methods limit for android. I solved it by include only google maps in play-services like this: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'. Now it works fine